# Android Button malfunction

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Im trying to get my two buttons to work.  The first button is supposed to display my first webview activity and the second button is to show the second webview activity.  Ive been playign around with my intents and so far ive come to the conclusion that it must have something to do with it because i have my second button displaying the first webview, but my first button doesnt do anything.  Any suggestions?

```
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       final Context context = this;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);


        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override           public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });







        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
                button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonurl2);

                button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity2.class);
                        startActivity(intent);







                   }});



    } }
```

Comment: have you tried assigning them to different button variables?

Comment: Remove the second call of `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` and `setContentView(R.layout.main);`

Comment: Thank you!!..couldnt have done it with out you

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have the lines:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

twice?  That could very well be the issue, since you reset the content view and thus lose the on click change you made before the second call of

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

In short, remove the second appearance of the above two lines to fix the problem.

Comment: I now see @dst may have beaten me to the punch ;)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above point by Jlewis071, i would recommend you to use two reference variable for two button.

Since you are making only one reference to hold button, so only last made reference is hold, and any previous reference would be discarded.

You should make

```
Button button1 = <your button1>;
Button button2 = <your button2>;
```